# MySQL - Error in foreign key constraint. Unable to create Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm having an issue with the Foreign Keys in MySQL and i'm really puzzled as to why it isn't working.

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL
    UNIQUE INDEX unique_user (username, email)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles (
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  role_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_role (
  user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The Foreign Key for the role_id can be created without an issue, but i'm having an issue with the user_id and i get the following error:

`Error in foreign key constraint of table user_role:
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.`

Can someone please enlighten me, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `integer` as the type for the IDs in all tables, not `int(11)` in some (the referencing one) (or vice versa).

Comment: @stickybit The `(11)` shouldn't matter, it doesn't affect the actual datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_role.user_id` is `INT UNSIGNED`, but `users.user_id` is just `INT`. They have to be the same datatype. Either change `user_role.user_id` to `INT`, or change `users.user_id` to `INT UNSIGNED`.